# Kinesis-contributed latency using Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-kinesis

We're building a (mostly) server less architecture centered around a Kinesis Stream being consumed by Lambda, and running into latency behavior that we don't understand and might block us.

We were experiencing high latency at extremely low volumes, so we set up a test case to measure it: our lambda does a few things, logs, and posts a message back to the same Kinesis stream to trigger the next invocation. This test logs 100-200ms of billed time, but the invocations come 2-4s apart according to Cloud Watch.

My reading suggests lambda should be polling 200ms after function completeness, so this seems very slow. I found some old posts from EOY 2014 that discussed similar behavior, but it appeared to be fixed in March 2015. Is this expected? If not, are there any gotchas that can result in slow invocation despite fast run times?

Some notes:
We are seeking <1s overall latency, so optimally < 500ms contributed by Kinesis.
We are using the python library for our lambda, so did not have `context.succeed()` or `context.done()` methods, if those might be relevant.
We have experienced configuring for greater memory, lower timeout, and different batch sizes with no effect.